# Menu interface is tiny in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The user interface on my title screen is so small. How can I make it appear bigger?
I'm playing on Windows 8.

[image: Tiny UI]

Comment: This isn't a glitch, it's just that your UI settings aren't the default.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Options > Video Settings and adjust the highlighted option (below) to taste.

The default setting is 'Auto'

[image: Video Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Make your GUI large, the option is under settings.